# Animation in quartz 2D

Tags: iphone, quartz-2d

I want to create an app which after each 1 second will show 4-5 words on screen but the last word will zoom out/in. I can easily create static words and for the last animating word i need to draw the static again n again.
How can i create 2 separate layers so the static text is on one layer ( i will fill it after each second) and the last word (animated one) will be on other layer.

How to create 2 separate layers? Attached on same screen but handling their drawRect method separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your query then you should make your own class which will be subclass of UIView and override drawRect method in the implementation, then create 2 objects of your custom UIView class at the place where you are making layer's object. you can have x,y co-ordinate variables which will work separately for both layers....

Comment: any code for creating 2 objects of my custom UIView class and how to attach it to main window?

Comment: //MyView.h
@interface MyUIView : UIView
{
   CGFloat wordX, wordY;
   NSString *word;
   //your animation specific variables
}
//MyUIView.m
@implementation MyUIView

-(void)drawRect {


  //Your animation code

}

//Usage in your view controller
-(void) method
{
   MyUIView *firstWord = [[MyUIView alloc] init];
   MyUIView *secondWord = [[MyUIView alloc] init];
   [self.view addSubview:firstWord];
   [self.view addSubview:secondWord];
}